# Is it possible to inset one column of a two column UIcollectionView in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I would like a misaligned collectionview layout like below:[image: my aim]

I've tried change the insets and padding ect but nothing has worked.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Post code that you tried

Comment: Each cell is the same, so I couldnt choose to do an inset on the right cell only, because it is one cell repeated with different data. Right now my code is just a normal collection view with 2 sections like so, and they are alligned together